# Is it possible to find all the video files using powershell?

Tags: powershell, video, powershell-2.0

Recently my colleague asked me is there way to find all video files using powershell.

I told him that using Get-childitem we have to include the video file extension in -include option.

He told that he is not sure what are all the video file formats are there . In windows search there is an option for searching video. Is there any similar option available in powershell?

His question seems to be valid , is there any built in option available in powershell to find video/Audio/picture files?

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

I stand corrected; there is a way of doing this, I have adapted the following link to find just video files: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/11084.aspx

```
$kind = "video"  
$folder = 'C:'

$objConnection = New-Object -com ADODB.Connection  
$objRecordSet = New-Object -com ADODB.Recordset  
$objConnection.Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';")  
$objRecordSet.Open("SELECT System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE System.Kind = '$kind' AND System.ItemPathDisplay LIKE '$folder\%'", $objConnection)  
if ($objRecordSet.EOF -eq $false) {$objRecordSet.MoveFirst() }  

while ($objRecordset.EOF -ne $true) {  
  $objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemPathDisplay").Value  
  $objRecordset.MoveNext()  
}
```

This code will finded all Video files within the given `$folder`.

Comment: There is a limitation to above approach and that is that the Windows OS would have to have indexed the path you are querying. Is e.g. mapped drive or even secondary drive such as D:\ is no part of the Windows indexing, then you are out of luck as this uses the Windows system DB rather than traversing actual directory structure.