How to loop through all video files (kind:video) regardless of what extension those files(could be .mkv / .mp4 / .mov etc.) have?
So I know that by using this command we can loop through all the MKV / MP4 files in the current folder. But I don't want to have to Google and find out what all possible file-types or extensions the genuine Video files could have like .webm, .mkv, .mp4, .mov etc.
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mkv | Foreach { $_ }
I want to loop through all those regardless of the file-types or extensions, as long their kind is Video file, by that I mean if you remember Windows folder search there's a parameter says kind:video that lists out all videos without getting into the file extension stuff.
How can I do that with Powershell script ??

Windows folder search does not include "Kind:video". Are you thinking of MacOS instead? Windows strictly uses the file extension to identify file types, and nothing else.

get-childitem *.webm,*.mkv,*.mp4,*.,mov

Using the windows search com object:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16295322/6654942

What if someone renamed the video file example.mp4 to example.docx, do you want to identify example.docx as a video file, too?

@js2010, not having to know and explicitly enumerate the individual extensions is the stated premise of the question. The COM API-based answer you link to is promising at first glance, but appears to have its problem; I've added a link to it and a discussion to my answer.


As for the interactive GUI perspective:Thanks, mclayton.

Windows Search supersedes Windows Desktop Search (WDS) v2.x; only the latter link directly shows examples such as kind:video, but the former points to the System.Kind documentation that implies that kind:video and alias kind:videos are still supported.

In practice, using these search terms in the search field of File Explorer yields image file as well as unrelated .ts files (TypeScript files), due to an accidental name collision with the filename-extension definition at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ts, which points to the WMP11.AssocFile.TTS file type, which is meant for MPEG-2 TS Video files. Other such false positives are possible.



In programmatic use:
You can emulate kind:video - i.e. a request to find all video files irrespective of their format - as follows:
# Get an array of wildcard patterns that match all filename extensions
# representing video files, e.g. @('*.3g2', ..., '*.mp4', ...)
$includePatterns = 
  (
    Get-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.* -ErrorAction Ignore | 
      Where-Object PerceivedType -eq video
  ).PSChildName -replace '^', '*'

# Filter the target directory by those wildcard patterns.
# Note: If you're targeting the *current* directory, you can simplify to:
#         Get-Item $includePatterns
#       With a given path, make sure to append \*
#       Add -Force to also match hidden files.
Get-Item .\* -Include $includePatterns  # | ...

Note:

The above finds the filename extensions associated with video formats that are already registered locally, which may therefore not cover all known video formats; see the next section for an alternative that derives all extensions from an online source.

The local definitions, as queried above, are stored in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry hive, where each known filename extension  has its own subkey (e.g., HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4) whose PerceivedType value classifies the files using that extension.

Presumably the source of the video formats used by Windows Search is the same set of registry definitions; this answer to a similar question shows programmatic use of Windows Search via its COM APIs, though a warning in a comment states that it works only with indexed locations, which would exclude networks shares and removable drives. Also, in practice, I've found kind:image to work interactively with an indexed local folder on C:, but not with the equivalent COM API solution. Additionally, such a solution is even more complex and obscure than the registry-based one above; however, when it does work, it is noticeably faster than the registry-based solution.



-Include supports multiple patterns as an (array) argument, separated with , which - unlike the single pattern supported by -Filter - are interpreted as PowerShell wildcard patterns.[1]

The above finds video files located directly in the current directory; doing so requires use of Get-Item .\* rather than Get-ChildItem, unfortunately, due to the unintuitive way the -Include parameter currently functions: see the bottom section of this answer.

To find video files in the current directory's entire subtree, replace Get-Item .\* with Get-ChildItem . -Recurse; -Include does work as expected with the latter.

-ErrorAction Ignore in the Get-ItemProperty call is used to ignore errors that - unfortunately - may result from registry keys whose names have embedded / characters, e.g. MAPI/IPM.Task. These errors are the result of PowerShell by design treating both / and \ as path separators, even though in the context of the Windows registry only \ is appropriate: see GitHub issue #5536.



Online solution, based on web scraping:
Note:

It's unclear to me whether there's an official online registry of all filename extensions representing video files; the IANA Media Types registry for videos defines media type strings, but seemingly not associated filename extensions.

The solution below relies on web scraping of https://fileinfo.com/filetypes/video

As with the GUI method and possibly also the registry-based method, there may be false positives due to name collisions; notably, as mclayton points out, the linked source lists .xml as an extension, for file type Cinelerra Video Project.
Therefore, you may want to implement hard-coded exclusions for such extensions.


$includePatterns = 
  [regex]::Matches(
    (Invoke-RestMethod https://fileinfo.com/filetypes/video), 
    '(?<=<a href="/extension/)[^"]+'
  ).Value -replace '^', '*.'

Get-Item * -Include $includePatterns | Foreach { $_ }


[1] See this answer for background information.

I might be talking cross-purposes, but fwiw it seems you can use a search term like "kind:video" in the Windows Explorer search box: - see https://i.sstatic.net/Mil281pB.png for example. Apparently it is / was part of "Windows Desktop Search 2.x" which is "obsolete" and replaced by "Windows Search" - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN#file-kinds. The PerceivedType registry keys seem to be related as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-perceivedtype

This code $includePatterns =   (     Get-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.* -ErrorAction Ignore |       Where-Object PerceivedType -eq video   ).PSChildName -replace '^', '*' -join "','" and, I had to surround the result string with quotes like I did with comma here because -Include only takes format like '*.mkv','*.mp4' with multiple video extensions. That previous line did give me the all video extensions though only the ones present in my system rather what I was expecting like making for API call online, but still when I put in -include pattern it doesn't work still

@mklement0 What I am saying here is, there's still some corrections needed in your answer, it gives me the extensions, but it doesn't fit the format needed for -include switch and so it doesn't find the video despite there's multiple video file types present in the folder I am searching in, eg. mkv, mp4, ts etc,

@mclayton Thanks, I knew the Windows Folder search (top right bar @mklement0) can be used with any kind of file like kind:video, because I've been using it since long. And I just wanna replicate that with Powershell script, but just not limited what's registered as Video in my OS / Harddisk, but a full compiled list online, for example if a new video format that isn't registered in my system registry, but if I have downloaded that video and not once watched it or opened it, I still want it found by this kind:video search I do with this Powershell script that you could help me build.

@mclayton, thank you for those links - I've updated the answer accordingly; the PerceivedType value in the registry is already a core part of the solution in this answer.

@VickyDev: Re -Include parameter: my bad: indeed you must pass an array of strings to -Include, so all that was needed is to remove -join ',' from the original form of this answer - please see my update.

@VickyDev: As for your desire to identify video files whether or not their format is defined in the local registry: it's not clear to me that kind:video - whose programmatic equivalent you're looking for - actually does performs this kind of online lookup. If you know that it does: what source does it consult? Either way, you should update your question to explicitly state this requirement.

@VickyDev: I've updated the answer to show an example of deriving all video filename extensions from https://fileinfo.com/filetypes/video - if you know of a more authoritative source, let us know.

@mklement0 - npyw, and +1 esp. because your answer addresses the OP’s additional requirements for exhaustive video types as well, but your cautionary point about file extension collisions also applies to the fileinfo.com list with the fun .XML for
Cinelerra Video Project :-). I guess the OP needs to decide if they want to find every known video type under the sun - including all the false positives - or just a curated subset…

@mklement0 Your updated answer worked perfect, also the online-api solution that you posted is accurate so far, so I am just gonna use that. If I find any other that has more video type listings, I'll update it here. Thanks a lot!!

Glad to hear it, @VickyDev; my pleasure.
